# To find $\dfrac{1}{e} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} b_{ij}$

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

> Let 
>   $
>    A=
>   \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
>    1 & 1 & 0 \\
>    0 & 1 & 1  \\
>    0 & 0 & 1  \\
>   \end{array} } \right]
> $
>   and $$e^A= I +A + \dfrac{A^2}{2!}+\dfrac{A^3}{3!}+...$$
>   If $e^A=[b_{ij}]$ then what is $$\dfrac{1}{e} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{3} b_{ij}$$

Can anyone suggest something how I should start? I can't think of anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $A=\operatorname{Id}+B$, where$$B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and since $\operatorname{Id}$ and $B$ commute, $e^A=e^{\operatorname{Id}}e^B$.